# how to validate mobile and also allow blank field in mobile in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

this code not works
i want to validate mobile and also allow blank submission of mobile field.

This code works for validation but not for nil field .

`validates :mobile, :numericality => {:allow_blank => true},:allow_nil => true, :length => {:minimum => 10, :maximum => 15}`

Comment: `nil.blank? #=> true`

Comment: Which rails version are you used ?

Comment: Try removing `:allow_nil => true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `allow_nil` to `allow_blank`. Chances are, you are submitting empty string `''`, instead of `nil` (json `null`) value. So, to allow it, you need to specify `:allow_blank => true`

Comment: i tried with two validation options , now it is working.. thanks to all for helpng me